# How can we refer external cmake file from main CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

Let's say I have some protobuf related cmake code as a library that resides inside **CMakeLists.pro** file and I need to include this library as a external file configuration. How to do that ?

Comment: Using [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) command you may include any CMake script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is asking how to make cmake modules. IE you have helper code and would like to make it easily available.

A normal top level project has a top level cmake folder. Here is an example of what that would look like.

- cmake
- tests
- src
- .gitignore
- CMakeLists.txt
- README.md

Inside the cmake folder say you have a cmake module called foo.cmake
(It's important to make the file end with .cmake file extension)

Anyway this is what your foo.cmake may look like

```
# Include guards need at least cmake 3.10
include_guard() # Good practice to use an include_guard()

function(bar)
...
endfunction()
```

Now in your main cmakelists how do you call this function? Simple.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

# Add the cmake folder to the cmake module path, this makes it easier to include files
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
# Include foo.cmake
include(foo)

# Call the bar function you defined in foo.cmake
bar()
```

And that's how you can refer to external cmake file from the main CMakeLists.txt